# Open python program on system startup

Tags: python, startup

I need my program to launch on system startup or user login. I have played around a little with the scheduler, but I'm pretty new to that and I couldn't get it to work. Basically I need to save something in the code to the startup registry.

It might also be worth to note that I will be turning this into an exe with pyinstaller, but that shouldn't make too much of a difference I believe.

Comment: On what OS are you?

Comment: I'm on windows 10

Comment: Take a look [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/228467/how-to-make-a-program-run-at-startup-on-any-computer/)

Comment: @StamKaly nice answer

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this requires me to manually put it into the startup registry. I need the program to automatically do this so that my friends who also installs it gets this as well. If it is possible to make the program do what the link suggest automatically I can look into that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Windows 8 / 10 startup folder location**

The Current Users Startup folder in Windows 8 and 10 is located at:

```
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

These programs start up for the current logged in user only. To directly access this folder, open Run, type shell:startup and hit Enter.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Od1o0.jpg)

Comment: I dont think it does for windows 8+

Comment: He is using windows 10

Comment: Yes, I need the program to automatically get put into that folder when you launch it :)

Comment: make a batch file and include this line "move c:\YourScript.py C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"

Answer (score 2):

you can use the old-good startup folder of windows, adding a bat file running your script or its exe version obtained  with pyinstaller.

Charlie